# typecasting object of one template type to another template type in c++

Tags: c++, class, templates

I created a stack class in c++ using templates. The program first asks the type of data to be entered in the stack for eg. int, float, char etc.
My doubt is if I created two objects like,

```
Stack<int> obj_integer(size);
Stack<char> obj_character(size);
```

Where Stack is the user-defined class using a template and size is the size of the stack passed by the user. Then how I will type cast the object "obj_integer" to object "obj_character". That is I want that obj_integer will now take char type data instead of integer type.

Comment: You can't. C++ does not work this way. You have to create a new object, from scratch, and initialize it appropriately. C++ does not do anything for you, you have to do it yourself. Of course, if you coded the appropriate template constructor or assignment operator, you can certainly say "obj_integer=obj_character" and make it work just like that, but you have to code the assignment operator that implements it, yourself. C++ will not do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your Stack looks something similar to this;

```
template<typename Type>
class Stack
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Stack(T t){}
};
```

you can static cast as;

```
Stack<int> obj_integer(1);
Stack<char> obj_character('a');
obj_integer = static_cast<Stack<char>>(obj_character);
```

this is one thing that you shouldn't be doing though. imagine what would happen if the `stack` had some members that wouldn't handle by static cast. you would end up with not properly handled conversion.

So the better alternative is overloading the assignment operators and copy constructors to make sure everything is converted correctly.

```
template<typename Type>
class Stack
{
public:

    // template < typename T>
    template < typename T>
    Stack( const Stack< T > & obj ) //copy conustructor
    {
        // do conversion
    }

    template < typename T >
    Stack& operator=( const Stack< T > & obj ) //overloading assignment operator
    {
        // do conversion
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Stack(T t){}

};


int main()
{

    Stack<int> obj_integer(1);
    Stack<char> obj_character('a');
    Stack<char> obj_character2('b');
    Stack<int> obj_integer2 = obj_character;  //copies the obj_character to  obj_integer2 using copy constructor
    obj_integer2 = obj_character2;            //assigns the obj_character2 to  obj_integer2 using assignment operator
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use C++17's `std::any`,  [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), or define your own object type:

```
Stack<std::variant<int, double, char>> obj_stack(size);
```

If `Stack` has an interface similar to `std::vector`, then the use would look like:

```
obj_stack.push_back(12);
std::cout << std::get<int>(obj_stack.back()) << '\n';
obj_stack.push_back('x');
std::cout << std::get<char>(obj_stack.back()) << '\n';
```

Also, look up `std::holds_alternative`, `std::get_if`, and `std::visit`. They can help you detect what type your element is, and act accordingly.

---

If C++17 is not a possibility, then it is possible to use [`boost::variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html)

If neither boost nor C++17 are an option, you can always define your own class hierarchy to hold the different types. But in that case you are most likely reinventing `std::any` and `std::variant`, which is not a good idea (unless your goal is to learn how these things can be implemented).

Comment: is std:: variants introduced for avoiding casting? it seems a bit overkill.

Comment: @Yucel_K the `std::variant` class makes it safe to insert different types into one stack. According to the question there is only one stack, where each entry can be of a different type. This is exactly what std::variant is for. Maintaining separate stacks and synchronizing them, in order to make them look as one stack, is error prone and inefficient.

Comment: hmm.. perhaps question needs a bit more clarification as in why he requires casting. from what I understood, he wanted to just cast one stack type to another.

Comment: @Yucel_K I agree that they wanted to cast one stack type to another. It seems like an xy problem to me. The real cause for the need of casting  seems to be able to work with different objects inside the stack.